# Restricting Test Send only to specific Domain

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, email, email-studio

Is there a way to restrict the test send from sending to a speicific email domain eventhough it's in the same group distribution with other emails?

For example, in my list i can have xyx@gmail.com and xyz@yahoo.com - during test send i set restriction so xyx@gmail.com don't receive test send emails.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using Ampscript in the email to scan for the email domain and execute RaiseError if _isTestSend == true?

Comment: @BradSapkota I've used data extenion created from **DomainExclusion** template to record email domains that should be exlcuded. I've also use the **Exclusion Script** as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [**Exclusion Script**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213980&language=en_US&type=1) and the [**Domain**](https://ampscript.guide/book/domain/) AMPscript function on the send definition:

```
domain(emailaddr) == "domaintoexclude.com"
```

And if you only want to exclude on test sends:

```
_isTestSend == true and domain(emailaddr) == "domaintoexclude.com"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is there a way to just include a specific email domain ONLY during test instead of exluding certain email domain. The situation is that since the volume of subscribers is high, it's better to include only targer email domains. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to add more on this - This is an exclusion approach. There are so many domains so using an exclusion approach would be difficult to plan for all domain options out there. An inclusion approach that limits just to xyz.com domain would be ideal.

Comment: There's not a good solution for the granularity that you're describing.  There is an account wide domain exclusion that can be enabled for your account, but it's not per email.

Comment: I just found a way to limit email domain during send - all i needed to do was to add the following: Domain (emailaddr) != "xyz.com". This will restrict email sends only to those domains. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found two ways to exclude email domains when sending email in SFMC:

1) Exclusion Script: during email send add the following script in the Advanced Exclusion section **Domain (emailaddr) == "gmail.com"** - This will exclude all subscribers with email domains with gmail.com

2) Domain Exclusion Data Extension - Create a data extension from the template DomainExclusion. This will have pre-defined attribute called Domain, which you can enter the domain to be excluded. You can then select the data extension in Domain Exclusion section in Advaced Exlusion during send time.

One way you can include only a specific email domain:

1) Exclusion Approach: Use the **Domain (emailaddr) != "xyz.com"** script, which will send email only to emails with xyz.com email domain.